# How to compare the updated webpage with the non-updated one automatically?

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, html-agility-pack

Apologize for my poor english.

I have to compare the details of the updated webpage with the non-updated one, such as the location and size of all elements.

I use google diff at first.If the html sources are the same, I would use selenium Webdriver to compare elements.

Here is the code.

```
IWebDriver d1 = new FirefoxDriver();
IWebDriver d2 = new FirefoxDriver();
d1.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
d2.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
compare();
d1.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL2);
d2.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL2);
compare();


public void compare()
{
   List<IWebElement> list1 = new List<IWebElement>();
   foreach(IWebElement e in d1.FindElements(By.CssSelector("*")))
   {
      list1.Add(e);
   }
   foreach(IWebElement e in d2.FindElements(By.CssSelector("*")))
   {
      list2.Add(e);
   }
   for(int i = 0; i<list1.Count; i++)
   {
      if(list1[i].Size.ToString()!=list2[i].Size.ToString())
      {
         //not the same size
      }
      if(list1[i].Location.ToString()!=list2[i].Location.ToString())
      {
         //not the same location
      }
   }
}
```

But it didn't work if it had read too much pages.
It may compare unmatched elements such as comparing A Element in page1 with B Element in page2.

So I tried to use HtmlAgilityPack to get Xpath list of all element with  the html source, and then call selenium to find elements by Xpath.

It worked luckily, but here is a problem.

When there are JavaScripts that would inserts some html tag to the webpage in the page, and selenium would execute them,so HtmlAgilityPack would get the wrong Xpath.

For example, the html is

```
<div>
</div>
```

So the Xpath is `//div`.

But after executing js, the html is

```
<div>
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The xpath is `//div/div`.

But HtmlAgilityPack still gets `//div` because it read the html source.

How could I solve it?

Thx for reading.

Comment: Not entirely sure what the point of this is. You want to compare pages A and B and know the differences? Isn't it *all* going to be different*?

Comment: For example,  comparing google site in the different version but the same page.

Comment: The source code may not changed but only the css was modified.